# Which one is better, longtable package or xltabular package?

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, xltabular

Which one is better, longtable package and xltabular package?
And if I use longtable package, should I use longtable for all tables or use just table package for not long table and use longtable package only for long table?
And Is there a long table version of the tabular* package?

Comment: This is a fairly subjective question. The advantage of `xltabular` is mainly the `X` type column, which os often more flexible than say the `p` column. Personally, I would recommend the new `longtblr` from `tabularray` package, but as I said, this is also subjective. About your second question. You should **not** use `longtable` (or any variants of it) for regular tables. Regular tables are usually `floats`, meaning LaTeX will try to place them according to your placement specification, e.g. `[tb]` for top or bottom placement. `longtable`s are alsways placed where defined and allow linebreaks.

Comment: My last comment should be "and allow pagebreaks".

Comment: which is better, an apple or an orange?

Comment: note that xltabular uses longtable they are the same really just that xltabular also has the X column from tabularx. If you do not need that then they are exactly the same code.